# Explain the Output of sizeof operator when applied to a function type

Tags: c, function, printf, sizeof

The output of following code is:

**Hello World4**

how?

```
#include "stdio.h"  

int func()  
{
    return(printf("Hello world"));
}

int main()  
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(fun));
    return 0;  
}
```

For more refrence please check the image [image]

P.S :- According to me, sizeof() call func() function in which return statemnt call printf function which print hello world nd return length of string which is 11 to the return function then sizeof() function return the size of 11 which is int and value of int depends on compiler either 2 or 4

Comment: Are you sure about that output? Can't see any call of `func` and where did the space between `d` and `4` come from?

Comment: That code does not compile in MSVC. And it wasn't the the code that produced what you say.

Comment: @4386427 I think answer is correct according to Theoretical point. But fails when runs on any IDE. Also, answer varies IDE to IDE.

Comment: The only way that "Hello World" could be output is if func() were called. But nowhere in the code that is the case. In `sizeof(func)` the `func` is a function pointer so even if sizeof weren't a special operator func would not be called. But sizeof is special and even `sizeof(func())`, which would actually be valid code, will not call func. The argument to sizeof is not evaluated, only the type is. `sizeof(func())` is the same as `sizeof(int)` and would be 4 on most systems.

Answer (score 5):

The `sizeof` operator can't be applied on a function.

**From C11 draft, 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators**

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
>   a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member.

So what you are doing is a *constraint violation* as per C standard.

Compiling with `-std=c11`, gcc produces the warnings:

```
$gcc -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic-errors s.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
s.c:10:23: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a function type [-Wpointer-arith]
     printf("%d",sizeof(func));
                       ^
test.c:10:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d",sizeof(func));
```

As you can see, there's another issue. You can't use `%d` to print `size_t`. `%zu` is the correct format specifier for printing `size_t`.

Comment: Just a small nitpick, probably the diagnosis is due to `pedantic-errors`, not due to `-std=c11`. (please refer to the links in my answer, it's the same in `-std=c99` also [strict mode]).

Comment: I know this, but If you run the code then you will get the answer but not the required one.
If you ignore C11 draft, appy dry run then answer is correct but not on IDE

Comment: This is not a question about C11 draft standard. Its about the real output of a C program.

Comment: If you ignore what standard (this is the same since the first C standard - C89) says and compile in a non-standard environment, then you have to consult the documentation of your compiler.

Comment: Well the questioner isn't interested in the standards - he just wants an explanation of why its 4 instead of 11.

Comment: @buffjape Surprise!! It's not 4 (at least no guaranteed)

Comment: Who said it was guaranteed?

Comment: @SouravGhosh 
According to me, sizeof() call func() function in which return statemnt call printf function which print hello world nd return length of string which is 11 to the return function then sizeof() function return the size of 11 which is int and value of int depends on compiler either 2 or 4

Comment: @harshitchandel `sizeof() call func() function`..nope, there is no _function call_ happening there....

Comment: @SouravGhosh do you have any other way to solve this question like this??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `%zu` format specifier to print the output of a `sizeof` operator, as the produced result is of type `size_t`.

That said, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4/ p1, The `sizeof` and `alignof` operators, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `sizeof` operator **shall not be applied to an expression that has function type** or an
>   incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that
>   designates a bit-field member. [...]

so, **your code is not conforming**.

- If you enable the `-pedantic` option with `gcc`, [you'll see the error (warning) as](https://ideone.com/crjdVL),

  > invalid application of `'sizeof'` to a function type
- Without the `-pedantic` option, [`gcc` compiles the code and produces a result as `1`](https://ideone.com/jN8RQk).

  **[It is](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith)** <del>likely to be</del> **a compiler extension for `gcc`.**

  Quoting from online gcc manual, (*my emphasis*)

  > In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to `void` and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a `void` or of a function as 1.
  >
  > **A consequence of this is that `sizeof` is also allowed on `void` and on function types, and returns 1.**
  >
  > The option `-Wpointer-arith` requests a warning if these extensions are used.

And finally, for a hosted environment, `int main()` should be at least `int main(void)`.